# Android ProgressBar not displaying properly on API 8

Tags: android, progress-bar

So I have this simpliest ever progress bar in load_more.xml file:

```
<ProgressBar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFB6C1" >
</ProgressBar>
```

I've added it as a footerview to my listview lv:

```
View footerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.load_more, lv, false);
lv.addFooterView(footerView);
```

It works as intended on virtual device (Android 4.3):
[image]

But when I'm trying to run this on real device (Android 2.3.5):
[image]

There is no error or even warning, it works fine, but it looks just ugly. Why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's taking the View's entire layout width and that's why it's acting weird, or may be it's just a bug. Not sure.

However, you can avoid it by setting the width to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But to be clear: the problem is not with width but with this ugly "circle". The difference in pictures' width is simply because one is from print screen and the other is a photo from camera.